# What programming language is iOS written in?

Tags: ios

What programming language is iOS written in? Is it **Obj-C** or **C/C++ + ASM**?

Comment: Please review the guidelines for posting appropriate questions on SO. Questions about general computing are not considered within the scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mach kernel would be written in C, with Assembler thrown in to boot.

Above that layer, the device drivers be written in same language, C, as well that interacts with the kernel, think graphics, sounds etc.

Above that level, the runtime libraries would be mixture of GNU libraries, mostly C, C++.

Then the entire framework would be written in Objective C/C++ wrapping around the GNU libraries at lower level.

This would equally apply to the desktop OS/X as well, as they share similar structures of the aforementioned software.